# How to write system output to a file without >filename in command line in php

Tags: php, command-line

I want to write my `system` output to a file with out using `>filename` in command line. Using the same format of the output.

```
system("ping -n 4 $host",$result);
```

Comment: @hakre - `passthru` passes the output back to the browser and not to a file.

Comment: @EdHeal: Right. http://php.net/proc_open looks more appropriate here.

Answer (score 0):

Use [exec](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php) instead. You can specify and array for the output to be stored in. You can then write that array to a file using [fopen](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php) etc.